# c++ overload [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript

I am trying to overload the subscript operator [] in my class which uses a linked list to create a map. This and several variations, like adding const, is what I have tried.

header

```
int& operator[](std::string key);
```

and then defining the overload in a seperate file

```
int& mapLL::operator[](std::string key){ 
   int val = this->get(key);
   return val;
}
```

this is the error I don't know how to fix

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:38:24: error: invalid types ‘mapLL*[const char [4]]’ for array subscript
 int a = list3["ghi"]; 
                    ^
mapLL.cpp: In member function ‘int& mapLL::operator[](std::string)’:
mapLL.cpp:110:9: warning: reference to local variable ‘val’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   int val = this->get(key);
       ^
```

Then in the main file I am trying this

```
mapLL *list3 = new mapLL();
list3->set("abc",1);
list3->set("def",2);
list3->set("ghi",3);
list3->set("jkl",1);
list3->toString();
cout << list3->get("ghi") << endl;
int a = list3["ghi"]; 
cout << a << endl;
delete list3;
```

get function

```
int mapLL::get(std::string key){
    bool found = false;
    node *me = (node *) first;
    if(is_empty()){
        return -2;
    }
    while(!found){
        if (me->getKey() == key){
            return me->getValue();
        }else{
            if (me->getNext() == 0){
                return -1;
            }else{
                me = (node *) me->getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `list3` is a pointer, so you would have to do `(*list3)["ghi"]`

Comment: Also, as the compiler is warning you, the method returns a reference to a temporary. This is definitely not what you want to be doing.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use dynamic memory allocation (e.g. operator new)?  This is not Java or C#.  You can declare `list3` as a local or global variable without `new`.

Comment: @Brian I just tried your suggestions and that worked is there a way I can rewrite the function so `list3["ghi"]` works

Comment: @cmb don't declare `list3` as a pointer. It doesn't need to be one.

Comment: @cmb The issue is not your function. You declared list3 as a pointer to mapLL so naturally you need to dereference it to get at the underlying object. Try declaring list3 like this `mapLL list3;` Then you could get `list3["ghi"]` to work.

Comment: Can you post get() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to refrain from using raw pointers and dynamic allocation.  Your issue stems from incorrect use of pointers.

Use direct declarations:

```
mapLL list3;
list3.set("abc",1);
list3.set("def",2);
list3.set("ghi",3);
list3.set("jkl",1);
list3.toString();
cout << list3.get("ghi") << endl;
int a = list3["ghi"]; 
cout << a << endl;
```

Comment: @cmb  ^^^^  this is the way to go ^^^

Answer (score 4):

```
int& mapLL::operator[](std::string key){ 
   int val = this->get(key);
   return val;
}
```

you are returning a reference to a local variable, `val`.

 what you actually need to do is to find the element in you linked list and return it as is, no assignment to local variables in between.

Plus, `list3`  is a *pointer*, unfortunatly, you need to dereference it before using `[]` operator :

```
(*list3)["ghi"];
```

all have being said + looking at your profile, I get that you come from a Java background. my advice - understand what is the difference between *stack* allocation and *heap* allocation. this is the very basic of the language. you need to use dynamically allocated objects (=using `new`) very rarely.

although Java hides away allocation details, this is maybe the one of the most important subjects in C++. not everything has to be a pointer. your starting point is stack allocated objects. move from there to dynamic /static allocation if it does not line with your needs.

Comment: my origonal idea was this `return this->get(key)` but it gave me this error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’`